# What is worksheet.Cells(row,col).Formula

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet

I was watching a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=deUsurvhesM) for comparing two excel worksheets and came across this:

```
cellVal1 = ws1.Cells(row, col).Formula
```

In the video he says that this assigns the value of the specified cell to the `cellVal1`. I've only seen people use `ws.Cells(row, col).Value` and can't seem to find anything about `.Formula` with regards to `.Cells(<row>,<col>)`

What does `.Formula` do and is it different than `.Value`?

Comment: The variable would end up with the formula and not the result of said formula.  So say in Cell(1,1) there is a formula `=Sum(1,1)`,  the `.Value` would return 2 but the `.Formula` would return `=Sum(1,1)` as a string.

Comment: Here are some links in a rough order of relevancy to your question: [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx), [Range.Formula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx), [Range.Text property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx), [Range.Value2 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx), [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx)

Comment: So when you do `Cell(1,1).Value` is `Cell` considered some type of subset of `Range`? Because I did see those _Range_ properties, but didn't realize they were related to _Cell_

Comment: I would tend to disagree with 'the video'. The close relationship (interchangeability) between Range.Value and Range.Formula would seem to dictate that the formula is going to be stuffed into `cellVal1` not the formula's result (aka .Value). If `cellVal1` was a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) then that cell would be be gaining a formula, not the formula's result. I guess that can be expected from someone using `Row` as a variable.

Comment: For **almost all** intents and purposes, `Cells(<row>, <column>)` can be treated as a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) with all the inherent properties and methods attached. The primary difference is in the method of defining the scope. Range can be readily more than a single cell but Cells requires the [Cells.Resize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176182%28v=office.11%29.aspx) to be more than a single cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.formula` part takes the formula inside the cell and `.value` only take the value you can see.

[image]

```
A1 = 2
A2 = 4
A3 = 6
```

In `A3` there is a formula `=A1+A2` if you use `.formula`, to put the formula inside `cellVal1` using `cellVal1 = Cells(3, 1).Formula` (that is equal to `Range("A3").formula`) you get `=A1+A2`, but if you use `.value` you got `6`. Remember if you try to store a string inside a int type varible, you get an error, because the formula is a string.

TIP: if you use `.formulaR1C1` you'll get `=R[-2]C+R[-1]C`

Comment: Big **plus** for avoiding the use of **Row** as a variable the way 'the video' did.